# How do websites detect my browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, user-agent

There are several discussions on how to code a website that is able to detect my browser (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browsers)). I wonder, how websites such as [whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) achieve to even detect it, if I spoof my user agent (e.g., with [Agentium](https://github.com/jichu4n/agentium))...?
[image]

Comment: you probably want to start here: https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/learn Note that there are about a hundred different things that each individually expose bits of your configuration, so there isn't one answer. The web works by letting software exchange information about its capabilities so that all the different platforms and software out there can share it. thats just part of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to have a definitive answer. Each Web browser has a distinctive signature. The Edge browser sends something like:

```
GET https://www.whatismybrowser.com HTTP/1.1
Host: www.whatismybrowser.com:443
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Microsoft Edge";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.48
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Cookie: privacy_consent_guest=CONSENTED%3A1664890623; lastvisit=1664914441; lastactivity=1664920887; vbprivacy_consent_guest=CONSENTED%3A1666023032; vbsessionhash=f6a8698605bdc7f2ef00a3a50eb63cd4; vblastvisit=1679194983; PHPSESSID=fftjqa0h3qbo28d9v18lgfp5nobvbtntt5t6tt86r5detvo1; vblastactivity=1681928773; _ga_RZEJWJ0N3V=GS1.1.1681928775.1.0.1681928775.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.558762357.1664890620; _gid=GA1.2.1029072516.1681928776
```

while Firefox send something like this:

```
Host: audiokeys.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: privacy_consent_guest=CONSENTED%3A1603133415; lastvisit=1664883576; lastactivity=1664884348; _ga=GA1.1.2025672830.1664883577; password=18f33f933cc6c56fbd61f03a755bcd3ec94be9617bb638a04dc19874; userid=45968; userstyleid=32; vblastvisit=1664970539; vblastactivity=1664971524; vbprivacy_consent_guest=CONSENTED%3A1664971501; vbpassword=18f33f933cc6c56fbd61f03a755bcd3ec94be9617bb638a04dc19874; vbuserid=45968; _gid=GA1.2.1739401847.1680040151; _ga_RZEJWJ0N3V=GS1.1.1681847671.60.1.1681852583.0.0.0; vbsessionhash=5aaf13ab69c92fd91b24d322bbb9e859
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

The field set is different and there is a lot of information that can be gathered, not only `User-Agent` which can be easily spoofed.

If this is not enough, the page can load a Javascript which probes the navigator further (But I guess the user agent seen by JS will be changed by your plugin too, then the script must be smart enough).

I have tried using `curl` to send blended queries. (The results are not processed by JavaScript). The first one with a `User-Agent` unchanged or spoofed. The results are Edge 112 and Chrome 70 (or even Safari 12). The second request gives Chrome 70. Then, a postprocess by Javascript seems to be very probable since I have no Chrome on my machine and the print on my browser is about Firefox.

Note, the sentence "Your web browser looks like:" is inside a Javascript. This confirms an interaction with a such script. The script can be downloaded here https://cdn.whatismybrowser.com/prod-website/static/main/js/site.min.js. It is quite obsfuscated, but you will recognize some browser models. Then there are many heuristics like "if there is such a property, it is Firefox..."

Answer (score 1):

The way the sites know where the browser is coming from is a string provided through HTTP in a header element called "user agent".

The User-Agent request header is a characteristic string that lets servers and network peers identify the application, operating system, vendor, and/or version of the requesting user agent.

That is (for instance) how the server will know to send you to an OSX download instead of a Windows download.  Also how it might know that you need a Windows X version and not a Windows Y version.

See this post:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: You miss the point. Here, the site tells YOUR BROWSER LOOKS LIKE... BUT IT I'S ANNOUNCING THAT IT IS... Obviously, the `User-Agent` field gives the second part of the answer. But not the first part. The question, is "how a Web browser identy can be detected dispite some cheating with the `User-Agent` field ?